# Proof - Percentage change in area if side of a two dimensional figure is increased by $x\%$

Tags: linear-algebra, area

> If each of side of a rectangle or any two dimensional shape is
>   increased by $x\%$, its area is increased by
>   $\left(\dfrac{x^2}{100}+2x\right)\%$
>
> Source: [careerbless.com](http://www.careerbless.com/aptitude/qa/percentage2_imp.php)

I am trying to generate a proof for the above formula. I succeeded in generating this formula for a rectangle. My proof is given below

Suppose sides are $p$ and $q$. Suppose each side is incremented by $x\%$

Initial Area $=pq$

New area $=p\left(\dfrac{100+x}{100}\right)q\left(\dfrac{100+x}{100}\right)=pq\left(1+\dfrac{2x}{100}+\dfrac{x^2}{100^2}\right)$

Increase in area $=pq\left(\dfrac{2x}{100}+\dfrac{x^2}{100^2}\right)$

Percent increase in area $=\dfrac{pq\left(\dfrac{2x}{100}+\dfrac{x^2}{100^2}\right)}{pq}\times 100=2x+\dfrac{x^2}{100}$

So, I succeeded in deriving the proof for a rectangle.

I proved the same using formula of area of a right angled triangle.

> But, I am not able to derive this formula generic for any two
>   dimensional shape. Can you please guide me on how to proceed further
>   for proving this formula for any two dimensional shape?

Comment: Why do you think that one formula would exist to cover all arbitrary shapes?

Comment: It does. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @sqtrat, that is how they defined this formula in the site mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer hinges on how you define area. One way is to define area for a rectangle, then use approximations by unions of rectangles and take some
limiting process to find the area of a more general shape. With this approach, if you know how stretching affects a
rectangle, then (skipping all the interesting detail) you can see that it will
change the area of the general shape in the same way.

In general, if you have a shape of area $A$ and you stretch it by a factor $s$ along one direction, then the new area will be $sA$.

If you stretch in two arbitrary directions by factors $s,t$ respectively,
the stretched area will be $s t A$.